# Xposed How to Create Instance of Generic Class with Interface

Tags: generics, interface, xposed

the following code is from decompiler

```
package com.myapp.pk1

public class B {
    ... ...

    public interface a<T> {
        void onFailed(String str1, String str2) 

       void onSuccess(T v1);    

    }
}


package com.myapp.pk2

public class MyCustomClass {
  ... ...
}
... ...

package com.myapp.pk3

public class C {
     ... ...
    public static void d(boolean var0, B.a<MyCustomClass> var1){
    ... ...
    }
}


package com.myapp.pk3


public class AppClass {
   ... ...
    C.d(v1, new B.a<MyCustomClass>() {
    public void a(MyCustomClass v3) {
    ... ...
    }

    public void onFailed(String var1, String var2) {


    }
    ... ...
}
```

Here the instance of B.a is the callback of method C.d
How can I reate an instance of that (interface?) with my own method of onSucces and onFailed?

Thnx a lot

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Where doe you got the interface declaration from? from source or decompiled app? Most generics only exists in source code and will be checked and removed from the compiler. Therefore only use the decompiled app and not the source code. You will most likely see that there are no generics at run-time (hence Xposed does not have to deal with them).

Comment: Thnx for ur quick reply. you are right, the code came from decompiler.   I create the instance by Class<Object>  instance = XposedHelpers;  The remaining problem is how to create methods to override onSuccess and onFailed, for they are interfaces which can not be replaced by xposed

Comment: @allen When writing a response in comments you should add the `@username` into your answer so that the person you are writing the answer to gets a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  I just realized that the interface must be inplemented by the class that really works as callback.  so I hooked that class and replace the method onFailed which has been implemented here.